# invoking java function in jsp with buttion

Tags: java, jsp, button, screenshot

I have a java function that I tested in a practice project that takes a screenshot of my jsp, how do I call the function from my JSP while using a button

this is the function I want to call

```
try{
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
    String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
    ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", new File(home +"\\Desktop\\test.jpg"));
}
catch(IOException ex){
    System.out.println (ex.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like the following way

inside JSP page submit a form with the same page with some temp data and check if the data is not null then there is action received for taking the photo.

```
<%

String a = request.getParameter("take");if(a!=null)
    {

        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            BufferedImage screenShot = robot
                    .createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
            String home = System.getProperty("user.home");

            ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", new File(home + "\\Desktop\\test.jpg"));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }

}%>

<form action="#"method="post">

<input type="hidden"name="take"id="take"value="take_photo"/><input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```